# Using font-awesome in a code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have the following code in my JSP file

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div style="text-align: left;" class="span3 row-fluid">
                <label><spring:message code="alert.channels.outbound.lines"></spring:message>:&nbsp; </label>
                </div>
                <div class = "span3">
                <div class="textbox">  
                 <div class="textVal">${alertStatusForm.outboundLines}</div> 
                    <div class="pencil span3 ">
                    <img src="/static/img/pencil.png" alt="Edit">
                     </div>
                    <div class="save span3">
                    <img src="/static/img/disk.png" alt="Save">
                    </div>
                    <div class="close span3">
                    <img src="/static/img/Cross.png" alt="Close">
                    </div>
                </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now I have to use the font-awesome in place of pencil.png , disk.png and Cross.png .
I have the following codes for the above pencil , disk and Cross as

```
Pencil =  icon-pencil (&#xf040;)
disk   =  icon-save (&#xf0c7;)
Cross  = icon-remove (&#xf00d;)
```

from the website http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Please let me know how to use the above codes in place of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this by change to `<i>` tag instead of `<img>`

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div style="text-align: left;" class="span3 row-fluid">
                <label><spring:message code="alert.channels.outbound.lines"></spring:message>:&nbsp; </label>
                </div>

            <div class = "span3">
            <div class="textbox">  
             <div class="textVal">${alertStatusForm.outboundLines}</div> 
                <div class="pencil span3 ">
                <i class="icon-edit"></i>
                 </div>
                <div class="save span3">
                 <i class= "icon-save"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="close span3">
                <i class= "icon-folder-close"></i>
                </div>
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Besure that you have link with font awsome css or
add this link in your layout or views

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `<IMG>` tags with the following:

```
<i class="icon-pencil"></i>
```

Setting appropriate class on the `<i>` element.

Comment: Do I need to import any link to include font-awesome in my page ?